# QGIS select by location failing

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm performing a simple select by location. I want to select polygons from TQ_Building that fall within rapidair_AOI, a larger polygon. My workspace looks like this:

[image]

I'm using QGIS 2.18.13. I've performed this through the Vector > Research Tools > Select by location menu, and through the python console (see code below) but no selection is made and a dialog box with 'unknown See log for more details' appears.

```
import processing
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()
processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation',layers[1],layers[0],u'within',0,0)
```

The layers share the same CRS, they are enetered correctly as input and intersect layers in the code. Any help / suggestions?

UPDATE: following @GeoDatup pointing me to log, here's the log message:

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm          Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>               File  "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py",
>   line 203, in execute
>                 self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SelectByLocation.py",
>   line 93, in processAlgorithm
>                 index = vector.spatialindex(inputLayer)
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py",
>   line 219, in spatialindex
>                 idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))           Exception: unknown

UPDATE 2017-11-03

The above was running QGIS 2.18.13 on Windows 2012 r2 server. I have also tried to replicate on my local Dell machine with the following results:

[image]

But there's no selection made in the mapviewer (which is what we'd expect given the second 0 parameter in the `selectbylocation` algorithm) and no extra polygons in the rapidair_AOI layer (used for the intersection enyway).

Comment: logs can be viewed  from menu  View > panel > log message

Comment: Assuming you're using 2.18, [that line](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py#L220) only gets called when the processing setting "Use only selected features" is unchecked (Processing > Options > General > Use only selected Features). What happens if you turn on that setting and retry?

Comment: "Use only selected features" was checked. I unchecked then get error box: 'Wrong value for parameter "Mysys folder": Specified path does not exist: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\mysys. This causes QGIS to hang. Force quite and re-open "Use only selected features" unchecked but `selectbylocation` statement has same non-result, same error msg. Will check Mysys folder.

Comment: @StevenKay OK. Trying to follow C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps\mysys. Find "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps" but no mysys ?file.

Comment: So, the mysys error was related to GRASS mysys folder in Processing>Options>Providers. Have set to blank. Still faced with same `selectbylocation` error.

Comment: @mark - Have you tried using `intersects` instead of `within` or perhaps increase the precision parameter?

Comment: @Joseph used `intersect` and adjusted precision but no joy. See update though.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.