# Receive this error log when running Join attributes by location

Tags: qgis, error, spatial-join

When I try running a join attributes by location in QGIS 2.18.13 I receive this error message which I don't understand:

`2017-11-22T09:39:55    2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SpatialJoin.py", line 147, in processAlgorithm
                index = vector.spatialindex(join)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py", line 219, in spatialindex
                idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))
            Exception: unknown`

Both of my layers are relatively large shapefiles and I have created a spatial index for each of them.

Comment: Is this an operation that you would normally complete without issues with your particular QGIS setup, therefore suggesting it could be something within the shapefiles? And If you export a small subset of each shapefile (they should overlap) are you able to complete the join?

Comment: duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/260401/55203).